# What's the difference between a == null and a === null?

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me by explaining the difference. From what I understand the === does an exact match but what does this mean when comparing with null ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/2958164

Comment: `undefined === null` is `false`, `undefined == null` is `true` -> in most cases you would use the `==` to handle both `null` and `undefined` at the same time.

Answer (score 27):

> What does this mean when comparing with null?

It means exactly what you already said: It checks whether the value is exactly `null`.

---

`a === null` is true if the value of `a` is `null`.

See [*The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm* in the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6):

> 1. If `Type(x)` is different from `Type(y)`, return false.
>   2. If `Type(x)` is Undefined, return true.
>   3. If `Type(x)` is Null, return true.

So, only if `Type(a)` is Null, the comparison returns true.

**Important:** Don't confuse the internal `Type` function with the `typeof` operator. `typeof null` would actually return the string `"object"`, which is more confusing than helping.

---

`a == null` is true if the value of `a` is `null` or `undefined`.

See [*The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm* in the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3):

> 2. If `x` is `null` and `y` is `undefined`, return true.
>   3. If `x` is `undefined` and `y` is `null`, return true.

Comment: cool stuffs, nice link!

Answer (score 0):

=== means it checks both the value and the type of the variables. For example pulled from the w3c page, given x = 5, x is an int, so x==="5" is false because it is comparing and int to string and x ===5 is true because it is both an int and the right value.

Comment: Good example, but OP is asking specifically regarding the comparison with `null` case.

Answer (score 0):

`===` is strict operator it not only compare value, but also type of variables so

```
string===string
int===int
```

`==` only compare values.

Answer (score 0):

Using the triple equals, the values must be equal in type as well.But not in ==.

i.e

```
1==true // this return true
1===true // but return false

a==null // will true if a is null or undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

`1==true` will be `true`

but `1===true` will be `false`

eg. `===` compares on data type level while using `==` JavaScript will typecast by it self