# simplify a function that takes two parameters: an array of array objects and a string key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to simplify a function that takes two parameters, an array of array objects and a string key, and returns an object with a structure

the function must return a structure of type.

```
{
 array[0][key]: array[0],
 array[1][key]: array[1],

_${key}s: [array[0][key], array[1][key]]
}
```

Here's my function:

```
function (array, key) {
  const result = {};
  if (array == null || undefined) return "(((Not data)))";
  for (let i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
    result[String(array[i][key])] = array[i];
  }
  const keys = {};
  let keyArray = array.map((item) => String(item[key]));
  keys[`_${key}s`] = keyArray.includes("undefined") ? [] : keyArray;
  return {...result, ...keys };
}
```

Limitations and warranties:
- it is guaranteed that the key values ​​of objects in the array (and nested objects) have only the following data types:
+string;
+number;
+null;
+undefined;
+ boolean;
- recommended time complexity of the function is O(n).
- the array parameter can take the values ​​null or undefined - in this case, the function execution should not fail with an error.
- if the key argument is not among the keys of array objects, the function must return a structure of the form:

```
{
  _${key}s: [];
}
```

I can't fulfill the last condition including

Comment: see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) also if your code is working possibly see [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibility with a `for...of` loop and using a negated [`Object.hasOwn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) call on the result to avoid adding duplicate keys to the `_${key}s` array. Keep in mind that you have not indicated how duplicate `array[i][key]` values should be handled an so right now only the last object with any given value will be kept in the result.

```js
function mapByKey(array, key) {
  if (array == null) {
    return `Invalid array`;
  }

  const result = { [`_${key}s`]: [] };

  for (const o of array) {
    if (Object.hasOwn(o, key)) {
      const keyValue = o[key].toString();

      if (!Object.hasOwn(result, keyValue)) {
        result[`_${key}s`].push(keyValue);
      }

      result[keyValue] = o;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(mapByKey(undefined, true));
console.log(mapByKey(null, "keys"));
console.log(mapByKey([], true));
console.log(mapByKey([{ stringKey: 1 }, { stringKey: 2 }], "stringKey"));
console.log(mapByKey([{ 1: "one" }, { 1: "one" }, { 1: "two" }], 1));
console.log(mapByKey([{ false: "one" }, { false: "two" }, { true: "three" }], false));
```

Note that `== null` will match both `null` and `undefined` see: [What's the difference between a == null and a === null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687983/whats-the-difference-between-a-null-and-a-null).

Comment: Your method solves the problems. Thank you. Only the complexity of On is quadratic it seems. And what about nested objects?

Comment: The method is O(n)  - a single traversal through the array. `Object.hasOwn` is an O(1) key lookup. And what nested objects, you don't mention them at all in the question?

Comment: substitute array and output, for example, city
```const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    age: 25,
    address: {
      city: "New York",
      zipCode: 10001,
    },
    name: "John",
    surname: "Doe",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    age: 30,
    address: {
      city: "Los Angeles",
      zipCode: 90001,
    },
    name: "Jane",
    surname: "Smith",
  },
];```

Comment: Your original question only notes `array[i][key]` not the passing of nested keys. If your constraints have changed either edit the question or ask another. If you are looking to pass nested keys I would recommend accepting a callback not a string key otherwise see: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I added a new question if you can answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098087/how-to-use-nested-object-values-and-keys

Comment: there's nothing stopping you from changing it 
```
if (array == null)     on       if (!array)
```

Comment: You can certainly test for `!array` but it is not as explicit in what it is testing for and relies on implicit coercion to a boolean. I prefer to be explicit about conditions and would probably actually do `if (array === undefined || array === null)` - minification will handle converting this to limit final bundle size, but when reading the code you know exactly what cases should fail.